# Datatables fnFilter Delay loader/indicator

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, datatables, delay

I am using datatables with a custom plugin I got from [here](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api) `fnSetFilteringDelay` but wanted to add an indicator or loader of some sort to tell the user when the search will happen on the typed text in the filter textbox. I have done this but it is a bit buggy, maybe someone can help me to get this fluent and beautiful.

[image]

But if you type more and more, the indicator bar starts to look like it is shattering.

I would like to get rid of the shattering part if possible.

Here is my code after initialising the datatables to variable oTable

```
oTable.fnSetFilteringDelay(550); //After the last character is entered, will take 550 milliseconds to search
$('#gvProjectList_filter input').parent().append($("<div id='lder' style='width: 0px; height: 30px; background-color: #999; float:right;'></div>"));
$('#gvProjectList_filter input').on('keyup', function (a) {
    document.getElementById("lder").style.width = "50px"; //Start the indicator at 50px and end at 0px
    var count = 550; //Same as the filtering delay set above

    var counter = setInterval(timer, 25); //will run it every 25 millisecond
    function timer() {
        count -= 25; //Minus 25 milliseconds
        if (count <= 0) {
            clearInterval(counter);
            document.getElementById("lder").style.width = "0px";
            return;
        }
        var neww = parseInt((count / 550) * 50); //calculate the new width vs. time left of 550ms
        document.getElementById("lder").style.width = neww + "px";
    }
});
```

Basically it must start at 50px width, and go down, when the user types another character, the bar must start at 50px again.

---

[**Here is my jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WSp8Y/), just type something to search, first one letter and then a whole name, you will see what I mean.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my own solution. I have made use of the jquery animate function

```
oTable.fnSetFilteringDelay(550);
$('#mytable_filter input').parent().append($("<div id='lder' style='width: 0px; height: 20px; background-color: #999; float:right;'></div>"));
$('#mytable_filter input').on('keyup', function (a) {
    $("#lder").width('50px');
    $("#lder").stop().animate({width:'0px'},550);
});
```

works like a charm!

---

[Here is the final Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WSp8Y/3/), check it out!

---

Comment: All I can say: Awesome!